# Hbase filter rows based on column and timestamp

Tags: hbase, filtering

I'd like to use the hbase shell to filter columns based on the column value timestamp.  For example:

```
f:my_qualifier  timestamp=1417542508438,  value=some value
```

I'd like to return all column values where the timestamp is > a particular timestamp. Is this possible using the hbase shell?  It looks like the TimestampsFilter requires a particular timestamp, I don't think it is possible to use a comparator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the TIMERANGE option:

```
scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}
```

Take a look at the scan command help for more options:

```
hbase(main):001:0> scan

Here is some help for this command:
Scan a table; pass table name and optionally a dictionary of scanner
specifications.  Scanner specifications may include one or more of:
TIMERANGE, FILTER, LIMIT, STARTROW, STOPROW, TIMESTAMP, MAXLENGTH,
or COLUMNS, CACHE

Some examples:

  hbase> scan '.META.'
  hbase> scan '.META.', {COLUMNS => 'info:regioninfo'}
  hbase> scan 't1', {COLUMNS => ['c1', 'c2'], LIMIT => 10, STARTROW => 'xyz'}
  hbase> scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}
  hbase> scan 't1', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('row2') AND (QualifierFilter (>=, 'binary:xyz'))) AND (TimestampsFilter ( 123, 456))"}
  hbase> scan 't1', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ColumnPaginationFilter.new(1, 0)}
```

Comment: To get TIMERANGE working for me I had to use millisecond timestamps. For example: the above timestamps with three trailing zeroes on each:
`TIMERANGE => [1303668804000, 1303668904000]`